# Stopping objects when collision occurs in sprite kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm building a game using Apple's SpriteKit and SKPhysics that use squares that move around on the screen based on user input.  I'm having an issue with collisions in that the squares will move out of place if they collide.  For example, if all the blocks move to the right, any blocks that are on the same "row" need stack next to each other and not overlap or move position vertically.  As of now, they will change their vertical direction.  Here is my code:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
```

Are there any other settings that I'm missing?

Comment: If you need precision movement it's best not to use physics for motion. You can try and set the x or y component of the node's position to a fixed coordinate during update for the time it shouldn't move along a specific axis. That's about all you can do.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be coming from your collisionBitMask category. In order to solve that, you need to first create categories for the blocks' physics bodies as follows:

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None : UInt32 = 0
    static let All : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let block : UInt32 = 0b1
    }
```

then set the blocks' settings to the following.

```
    block.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.block
    block.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
```

This should prevent the collision calculations from being automatically carried out by spritekit.

Comment: This seems the easiest solution and worked great for my little Pong test. It's definitely cleaner that the answer with most upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving your sprites via user inputs(i.g. SKAction's moveTo), then you're most likely not using physics to move your sprite. In this case, you should make the velocity of the physicsbody to 0- this will make the sprite completely rigid when it comes in contact with another object.

Try:

```
self.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
```

You should put this code inside your update loop.